# linking pdfium on linux

Tags: c++, linux, makefile, pdfium

I'm trying to use the pdfium libraries in linux(debian 64-bit). I managed (finally) to compile the release _x64 version of pdfium and the test programs seem to work. However, I can't seem to to use the libraries in a separate project.
This is my file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "fpdfview.h" 
#include "fpdftext.h" 
#include "fpdfdoc.h" 
#include "fpdfedit.h"
main(){
 FPDF_InitLibrary();
 std::cout << "Hello World!"<<std::endl;
 return 0;
}
```

And this is my Makefile:

```
CC = g++
CFLAGS = -Wall  -g -Wno-unused-variable -Wno-reorder -I/usr/include/pdfium/core/include  -I/usr/include/pdfium/fpdfsdk/include  -I/usr/include/pdfium/third_party  -I/usr/include/pdfium/v8/include
LIBS_pdfium =  -static -L/usr/lib/pdfium
LDFLAGS = $(LIBS_pdfium)

Main : Main.o 
    ${CC} ${CFLAGS} Main.o ${LDFLAGS}  -o Main

Main.o : Main.cpp  
    ${CC} ${CFLAGS} -c -std=c++11 Main.cpp

clean:
    rm *o Main
```

When I run the makefile the result is:

```
g++ -Wall  -g -Wno-unused-variable -Wno-reorder -I/usr/include/pdfium/core/include  -I/usr/include/pdfium/fpdfsdk/include  -I/usr/include/pdfium/third_party  -I/usr/include/pdfium/v8/include     Main.o -static -L/usr/lib/pdfium  -o Main
Main.cpp:11: error: undefined reference to 'FPDF_InitLibrary'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I've also tried to use the libraries in /home/username/pdfium/out/Release_x64/obj but got the same error

I know that error: `undefined reference to FPDF_InitLibrary`  means that there is a linking error. Therefore I checked the libraries in /home/username/pdfium/out/Release_x64/obj using objdump and one of them contained the InitLibrary symbol. This doesn't seem to make sense...

I don't know if I am referring to the wrong paths in the include or the libraries or if it is something else that is wrong.

I tried to understand the chromiums pdf plugin project makefile since I thought that might help me understand what I am supposed to use but unfortunately it didn't help.

Any ideas for what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Check if the test programs are wrapping the fpdf includes in an `extern "C" {}` block (or maybe the test programs ar `.c` not `.cpp`, then this block is not needed). If so, you must add the `extern "C" {}` around the fpdf includes. That is the first thing that comes to mind.

Comment: Thanks @RudolfsBundulis  I looked at one of the tests and they don't have extern "c" and it is a cpp file. In the include files there is an extern "C" . Is that relevant?

Comment: If the `extern "C"` is wrapping the same include files that you are using it is relevant (well to be precise - it is relevant if it is used around the include that declares `FPDF_InitLibrary`). But not to waste time with the tests - just try adding the `extern "C" {}` to your application - most likely it is what you need to solve this.

Comment: still getting the same error :(

Comment: can you update the code in the question so I can see how it looks now?

Comment: Ahh sorry, my bad, I actually wasn't paying enough attention - in the makefile you do not specify a library to link against. Shouldn't the `LIBS_pdfium` contain the names of libraries to link against? You are specifing only the path with `-L` but no actual libraries.

Comment: When I specify libraries I get errors like usr/lib/pdfium/libpdfium.a(fpdfview.o):fpdfview.cpp:function FPDF_LoadPage: error: undefined reference to 'CPDF_Document::GetPage(int)'

Comment: should I still update the code?

Comment: Hmm, is that the only library needed? You could use objdump as you did before to see which file provides the `CPDF_Document::GetPage(int)` function.

Comment: I linked to all the libraries that pdfium contains

Comment: Ok, not sure how to help further on. I'd say you could find which file has the `GetPage` with objdump, if it is linked in then there's a question why the symbol is not resolved.

Comment: could I have built pdfium incorrectly? or referred to libraries that are in the incorrecct place?

Comment: Well if the test programs link fine I suppose pdfium should be ok, it's actually to little information to tell exactly. As I said, in your place I'd use objdump to find out what exactly is going on.

Comment: I looked at the example makefiles and I figure out I needed to use a few more non-pdfium libraries so that everything would link properly. Thanks!

Comment: Well as I said, there were missing libraries:)

Comment: Can you add an answer below that lists the needed link flags for future searchers?

Comment: @user3872358 Are you able to create library ?

Answer (score 1):

To compile with PDFium the link line will depend on if you've compiled V8 and/or XFA into your PDFium binary.

With neither of those things enabled you'll need something similar to:

```
PDF_LIBS="-lpdfium -lfpdfapi -lfxge -lfpdfdoc -lfxcrt -lfx_agg \
 -lfxcodec -lfx_lpng -lfx_libopenjpeg -lfx_lcms2 -lfx_freetype -ljpeg \
 -lfx_zlib -lfdrm -lpdfwindow -lbigint -lformfiller -ljavascript \
 -lfxedit"
PDF_DIR=<path/to/pdfium>

clang -I $PDF_DIR/public -o foo foo.c -L $PDF_DIR/out/Debug -lstdc++ -framework AppKit $PDF_LIBS
```

public/ is the only directory you should use when working with PDFium for headers. The `-framework AppKit` is needed on OSX. The PDFium headers are in plain C but you need `-lstdc++` as PDFium uses C++ internally and it needs to be able to link in new/delete.

If you're working with V8 you'll need to add in:

```
-lv8_libbase -lv8_libplatform -lv8_snapshot -licui18n -licuuc -licudata
```

and if you're using XFA you'll need the V8 includes plus:

```
-lfpdfxfa -lxfa  -lfx_tiff
```

EDIT
There was recently a `pdf_is_complete_lib` option added to the PDFium build. Setting that to `true` in your `gn args` will create a single libpdfium that can be linked agains. Note, this has only been tested with V8 and XFA disabled.

Answer (score 1):

Args file..

```
# Build arguments go here.
# See "gn args <out_dir> --list" for available build arguments.
is_debug = false
pdf_is_standalone = true
pdf_use_skia = false
pdf_use_skia_paths = false
pdf_enable_xfa = false
pdf_enable_v8 = false
is_component_build = false
clang_use_chrome_plugins = false 
pdf_is_complete_lib = true
use_custom_libcxx = false
```

Then `gn gen your/dir/catalog`.

Then `ninja -C your/dir/catalog pdfium_all` and you take `pdfium.a`

In Linker

```
...
g++ -L-I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -o bin/debug/pdfium_test obj/debug/main.o   
...
```

you must have 
`-pg -s -Wl,--start-group /home/a/repo/pdfium/out/release/obj/libpdfium.a -Wl,--end-group -lpthread -ldl -lpthread`

Linking is ok.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't personally built it - because it was too time taking. But I managed to make it work with my golang application using cgo. I used ubuntu 16.04 as my base image in docker. This depends on https://github.com/bblanchon/pdfium-binaries

Following dockerfile downloads the pdfium binary and links to the app you are developing using pkg-config.

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
# Specify pdfium version
ARG PdfiumVersion=4026

# Install pkg-config, etc.
RUN apt-get -yqq update && apt-get clean && apt-get install -yqq apt-utils pkg-config tzdata && dpkg-reconfigure -f noninteractive tzdata

# Create .pc file for pkg-config
RUN echo "\n" \
     "prefix=/home\n" \
     "Name: pdfium\n" \
     "Description: pdfium\n" \
     "Version: $PdfiumVersion\n" \
     "Requires:\n" \
     "Libs: -L/home/lib -lpdfium\n" \
     "Cflags: -I/home/include\n" >  /home/pdfium.pc

# Download and extract pdfium binary
RUN cd /home && wget --quiet https://github.com/bblanchon/pdfium-binaries/releases/download/chromium%2F$PdfiumVersion/pdfium-linux.tgz \
&& tar -xf pdfium-linux.tgz && rm pdfium-linux.tgz

# Setting up paths for pkg-config
ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/lib
ENV PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/home/

## COPY YOUR APP TO /app/src/yourApp
# BUILD YOUR APP
WORKDIR /app/src/yourApp

# RUN your app which is linked to pdfium
ENTRYPOINT [“./yourApp"]
```